# Sass mixins: having issues with translateX and translateY

Tags: css, sass, css-animations, keyframe

I created a mixin to animate opacity and horizontal/vertical position. I've read through the documentation on SASS site. The mixin currently animates the opacity but fails to move elements -- translateX and translateY.

```css
@mixin keyframes($animation-name, $axis, $start, $end) {
  @keyframes #{$animation-name} {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
      transform: #{$axis}(#{$start});
    }

    50% {
      opacity: 1;
    }

    100% {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: #{$axis}(#{$end});
    }
  }
}

@include keyframes(slideLeft, translateX, 0, 200px);

.slide-left {
  animation: slideLeft 2s ease .1s forwards;
}

.redbox {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="redbox slide-left">
</div>
```

Here is a link to the JS fiddle that supports SCSS: [enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/joelhoelting/y86hxq0q/)

I've been banging my head for a while trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is how Sass is compiling the code. You need to use a literal string for the definition of the transform value (the `translate` function). So you need to create the value of the property as a string and then use the `unquote` function to output the value:

```
@mixin keyframes($animation-name, $axis, $start, $end) {
    @keyframes #{$animation-name} {
        0% {
            opacity: 0;
            transform: unquote("#{$axis}(#{$start})");
        }

        50% {
            opacity: 1;
        }

        100% {
            opacity: 1;
            transform: unquote("#{$axis}(#{$end})");
        }
    }
}
```

Demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/muecas/y86hxq0q/2/).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the answer. Never even knew this could be done. I couldn't find much in the documentation. How did you learn about this?

Comment: @JoelHoelting I never experienced with a case like this one. I just compiled your code and saw that the line with the transform wasn't even compiled, so i just thought Sass would be rendering all the `(#{$var})` stuff as a mathematical operation instead of a string. So, let's test doing it the stringy way and voilá! :-)